# Link to /help/badges from user profile ?tab=badges page

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page

It would seem to make sense that on the Badges tab of a user's profile page, there'd be a link to all the different badges and interpretations on that site.  Perhaps the currently-non-hyperlinked word "Badges" at the top of the list (following the number of badges that person has) would be a good place for it.

Comment: By "currently-non-hyperlinked" I mean that the word is there in plaintext; it's not a hyperlink.

Answer (score 5):

Is there any point? The `Badges` link is at the top of every page on every SE site you visit - I don't think there's any need to add *another* link to the same page to save you from scrolling up a tiny bit...

[image]

Comment: More for people who have tuned out that bar or who expect it to lead to different coarse categories of content, and who are looking for specific contextual information in the context of where it's being used rather than in a part of the page that's always there.  

Your point is reasonable, but is there any reason *not* to add the link closer in context?

Comment: @WBT There isn't exactly any reason not to - but if you want to access the list of badges, you know there's a link at the top of the page - just click that! But you make a fair point - people do tend to ignore headers like that after a while...

Comment: @WBT You usually discuss why there *is* a need, not why there *shouldn't* be something alike. SE devs don't get the time to implement every single feature people request. It has to be of considerable value.

Answer (score 0):

It already *is* on that page, it's on every profile page at the top.

Why do we need what is a *non-urgent* area of the site linking more than once on the same page?

---

> More for people who have tuned out that bar

Then they simply need to *re-tune in* if they want to see the badges page.

> or who expect it to lead to different coarse categories of content

Then they simply do not know what that bar is for, and the same can be applied to any function on the site which people are not familiar with.
Do we have duped links to try to resolve that?

All they have to do is click it, and can see it's the badges page.

To be honest, I know what you mean here, but the site has a *lot* of systems, features, and functions, and more than a basic forum it does take a little learning and time to work it all out.
But duplicating links would just add confusion to this, as not only do you have *more* links and stuff all over, but people will wonder whether *badges-link-A* is different to *badges-link-B*.

> and who are looking for specific contextual information in the context
>   of where it's being used rather than in a part of the page that's
>   always there.

But then we'd have dupe links all over the place, as most of the site's features have some kind of link or context to most others, in some way.

e.g. Badges are also given from "rep", and "bounties", so where do we draw the line of inter-linking to other things which are *vaguely relevant to another*?
Do we link to badges from "rep user has earned" page, and "bounties user has earned/given" pages too?

I think we should keep things as whereby they have their own specific area separate to others (mostly).
This makes it easier to learn, and easier to remember once learned.

> is there any reason not to add the link closer in context?

Yes, the context is not directly contextual, in that one is "badges a user has earned" and another is "all badges the site offers".

It's not exactly a biggie, but once you head down this path, you end up with a UI with dupe links and actions all over the place, and it not only gets cluttered and messy, but frustrating to use - especially for newer users.

Also, "is there any reason not to" is not a valid reason to do it.
You have a feature request, so should give reasons why this would be beneficial.
(Other than you personally want a link to the badges page on your earned badges area).